# How does the java compiler find the class files whereas the classpath is not set to the jdk path?

Tags: java, classpath, javac, dos

I'm trying to look under the hood about java compilation. So I put my IDE away and started using MS-DOS command-line...

I created a simple project, as described in the tree below :

**SampleApp**

```
|____**src**

       |_____pack
               |______Sample.java
|____**classes**
```

This is the Sample.java source code :

```
public class Sample 
{

    private String s = new String("Hello, world");

    public Sample(){
          System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

I just want to compile this class, so I used the javac command :

```
prompt\SampleApp\src>javac -d ..\classes -sourcepath . pack\Sample.java
```

All works fine, but i didn't expect that because I deleted my `CLASSPATH` environment variable before compiling my Sample.java file. So I was expecting a compiler error due to the fact that the compiler would not be able to find the java.lang.String class file.

I read this article http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-classpath-windows/ which helped me understand many things. The article author says that the default classpath is the current working directory. But I don't understand why my source code compile without error. Could someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So I was expecting a compiling error due to the fact that the compiler would not be able to find the java.lang.String class file.

The short answer is that the compiler *knows* where to find all of the standard Java SE library classes without you telling it.

The longer answer is that `String` class is being found on the bootclasspath.  This is *implicitly* set by the `javac` command to refer to the relevant JARs in the JDK installation.  The `javac` command searches the bootclasspath before it looks for stuff on the regular classpath.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It really helps me! I'll look for further information about bootclasspath.

Answer (score 5):

The classpath variable doesn't do what you think. To cite the oracle documentation:

> The CLASSPATH variable is one way to tell applications, including the
>   JDK tools, where to look for user classes. (Classes that are part of
>   the JRE, JDK platform, and extensions should be defined through other
>   means, such as the bootstrap class path or the extensions directory.)

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Basically since `java.lang.*` is part of the platform and delivered with the JDK/JRE, the compiler doesn't have to be told by you where to look for them.